# md-toast cause md-dialog to be transparent

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

On screen *S1* in my webpage, I'm opening a full-view with *md-dialog* and then after clicking on some button on the full-view (while md-dialog is active) I pop up a message using *md-toast*.

Right after the toast message popes up, the full-view become transparent and showing mostly the original screen *S1* (with some buttons and text from the full-view screen).

Even after I press a some button on the toast box to dismiss the toast, the toast message disappear but the full-view screen continue to be transparent.

Poping the toast on a regular screen without *md-dialog* (like on screen *S1*) works fine.

I found that when inspecting elements (on *Chrome*) -> style, under the css `.md-dialog-container`, `position:absolute` is checked, but **after unchecking and checking it back, the *md-dialog* full-view looks fine and not transparent anymore** (maybe it can assist to obtain the problem and proper solution).

```
.md-dialog-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 80;
  overflow: hidden; }
```

Decleration on my service file (angular):

```
@Inject('$mdDialog') private $mdDialog:  angular.material.IDialogService,<br>
@Inject('$mdToast') private $mdToast: ng.material.IToastService,
```

I tried to find similar issue or bug in the *md-dialog/md-toast* but couldn't find something related to my problem.

Same behavior also on *Firefox*.

Comment: Try to create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) to help us to resolve your problem

Comment: I am trying, it's a lot of code and I am new in this technology to find out which code is relevant and can recreate the problem. thanks!

Comment: Please use the [tag:angular-material] tag instead of [tag:angular-material2] tag.

Comment: @Edric Why ? He is using [angular-material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) I guess, no ?

Comment: @JeanJacques Isn't it obvious? There are no such types like `angular.material.IDialogService` in [tag:angular-material2]! (In angular material 2, it's just `MdDialog`)

Comment: @Edric If I ask you this question, it's because it's not that obvious bro, no need to be condescending... Because i'm pretty sure that it's some Angular2 code and afaik it's not possible to use [Angular-Material](https://material.angularjs.org) with Angular2 !